# Website crash after updating the admin url

Tags: magento2

After changing the admin url website crashed. Now i am trying to change the url back but i can not access my admin panel. What to do[image]

Answer (score 1):

Access your database and find the "core_config_data" table.

You need to change two values in these rows:

1. One with the path "web/unsecure/base_url"
2. The other with the path "web/secure/base_url".

Change the base URL values there. If you have SSL or if the admin panel is set to use secure URLs then make the "web/secure/base_url" include "https" so you would use https://www.youdomain.com/ while the "web/unsecure/base_url" can be http://www.youdomain.com/

You need the trailing slash in both values.

Once you change the base URLs you should clear cache and purge varnish. Then run the command to recreate your static content with the new URL.

> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

If you want to keep the new URL as it is check the "core_config_data" table and if the new URL is set in there try clearing cache/purge varnish and deploy static content. That might fix it so you may not need to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Remove var/cache and var/page_cache and check.